# Updating embedded excel (OLE object) in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

I have an embedded Excel-Sheet in Visio that represents the content of an array.
Filling this sheet works fine, but after finishing the macro there are no values visible in the sheet until I manually open (double klick) the ebedded excel.

Do I need to explicitly update an OLE object or what do I need to do to see any changes in Visio immediately?

Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
Dim ws As Object

Index = ActiveDocument.Pages("Vorlage").Index

Set acc3 = New Access_Schnittstelle

Set ws = ActiveDocument.Pages(Index).OLEObjects(1).Object.Sheets(1)

range1 = XYZ

ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(10, 10)) = range1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just 'solved' that issue with saving the file after finishing the macro.

This in some way 'updates' all embedded Excel objects in my Visio Document.